# lzw decompression algorithm in java for given compressed text

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, compression, lzw

I have following compressed text given as a byte Array:

```
byte[] compressed = [97, 2, 10, 28, 72, -80, -96, -63, -125, 8, 19, 42, 92, -56, -80, -95, -61, -121, 16, 35, 74, -100, 72, -79, -94, -59, -117, 24, 51, 106, -36, -56, -79, -93, -57, -113, 32, 67, -118, 28, 73, -78, -92, -55, -109, 40, 83, -86, 92, -55, -78, -91, -53, -105, 48, 99, -54, -100, 73, -77, -90, -51, -101, 56, 115, -22, -36, -55, -77, -89, -49, -97, 64, -125, 10, 29, 74, -76, -88, -47, -93, 72, -109, 42, 93, -54, -76, -87, -45, -89, 80, -93, 74, -99, 74, -75, -86, -43, -85, 88, -77, 106, -35, -54, -75, -85, -41, -81, 96, -61, -118, 29, 75, -74, -84, -39, -77, 104, -45, -86, 93, -53, -74, -83, -37, -73, 112, -29, -54, -99, 75, -73, -82, -35, -69, 120, -13, -22, -35, -53, -73, -81, -33, -65, -128, 3, 11, 30, 76, -72, -80, -31, -61, -120, 19, 43, 94, -52, -72, -79, -29, -57, -112, 35, 75, -98, 76, -71, -78, -27, -53, -104, 51, 107, -34, -52, -71, -77, -25, -49, -96, 67, -117, 30, 77, -70, -76, -23, -45, -88, 83, -85, 94, -51, -70, -75, -21, -41, -80, 99, -53, -98, 77, -69, -74, -19, -37, -72, 115, -21, -34, -51, -69, -73, -17, -33, -64, -125, 11, 31, 78, -68, -72, -15, -29, -56, -109, 43, 95, -50, -68, -71, -13, -25, -48, -93, 75, -97, 78, -67, -70, -11, -21, -40, -77, 107, -33, -50, -67, -69, -9, -17, -32, -61, -117, 31, 79, -66, -68, -7, -13, -24, -45, -85, 95, -49, -66, -67, -5, -9, -16, -29, -53, -97, 79, -65, -66, -3, -5, -8, -13, -21, -33, -49, -65, -65, -1, -1, 0, -61, 4, 20, 56, -112, 96, 65, -125, 7, 17, 38, 84, -72, -112, 97, 67, -121, 15, 33, 70, -108, 56, -111, 98, 69, -117, 23, 49, 102, -44, -72, -111, 99, 71, -113, 31, 65, -122, 20, 57, -110, 100, 73, -109, 39, 81, -90, 84, -71, -110, 101, 75, -105, 47, 97, -58, -108, 57, -109, 102, 77, -101, 55, 113, -26, -44, -71, -109, 103, 79, -97, 63, -127, 6, 21, 58, -108, 104, 81, -93, 71, -111, 38, 85, -70, -108, 105, 83, -89, 79, -95, 70, -107, 58, -107, 106, 85, -85, 87, -79, 102, -43, -70, -107, 107, 87, -81, 95, -63, -122, 21, 59, -106, 108, 89, -77, 103, -47, -90, 85, -69, -106, 109, 91, -73, 111, 91, 2];
```

and a given codeword length of `9 bits`.

The resulting string should be `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...` with a total length of 39270 of all `*a*s`.

I want to write a decompress function which decompresses the compressed byte array and returns the resulting string of `*a*s`.

I tried the normal LZW implementations but this didn't work very well. The given codeword length of 9 bit and the negative values in the byte array gives me some headache.

My understanding is I have to convert the whole byte array to one binary string and read each value every 9 bits (codeword length)?

Has anyone a hint or a suggestion how this can be done? Thanks, I really appreciate your support.

Edit:

Here is some code, I tried so far, which works with

```
byte[] compressed = [68, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 101, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 107, 0, 117, 0, 114, 0, 122, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 84, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 116, 0]
```

and a given codeword length of 16 bits.

The resulting string is `Das ist ein kurzer Text`.

```
public static List<String> convertByteArrayToBinaryStringList(byte[]compressedData,int codeWordLength){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        List<String> binaryCompressedValues=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<compressedData.length;i++){
            sb.append(byteToBinaryString(compressedData[i]));
        }

        char[]binaryCharArray=sb.toString().toCharArray();

        int j=0;

        while(j<binaryCharArray.length){

            StringBuilder binStringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=j;i<j+codeWordLength;i++){

            if(j+codeWordLength>binaryCharArray.length){
                System.out.println("End reached!");
                binStringBuilder.append("0");
            }else{
                binStringBuilder.append(binaryCharArray[i]);
            }
        }

        j+=codeWordLength;

        binaryCompressedValues.add(binStringBuilder.toString());
        }

        return binaryCompressedValues;
        }

public String incrementDictSize(String currentDictSize) {
    String incrementedString = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(currentDictSize, 2) + 1);

    int lengthDistance = currentDictSize.length() - incrementedString.length();

    String padding = "";

    if (lengthDistance > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthDistance; i++) {
    padding += "0";
    }
    }
    return padding + incrementedString;
    }

public byte[]uncompress(byte[]compressedData){
        int codeWordLength=16;

        List<String> binaryCompressedValues=new ArrayList<String>();

        binaryCompressedValues=convertByteArrayToBinaryStringList(compressedData,codeWordLength);

        //int dictSize = 256;
        String dictSize="1111111100000000";

        Map<String, String> dictionary=new HashMap<String, String>();
        String s="00000000";
        String padString="00000000";

        for(int i=0;i< 256;i++){

            s=String.format("%8s",Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ','0');
            dictionary.put(s+padString,""+(char)i);
            System.out.println("dictionary.get("+i+") "+s+padString+" "+dictionary.get(s+padString));
        }

        //String w = "" + (char)(byte)compressedData[0];
        String w="";

        StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer(w);

        for(String k:binaryCompressedValues){
        String entry;

        if(dictionary.containsKey(k)){
        entry=dictionary.get(k);

        dictionary.put(incrementDictSize(currentDictSize),w+entry.charAt(0));
        result.append(entry);
        w=entry;
        }else{

        entry=w+w.charAt(0);

        result.append(entry);

        dictionary.put(incrementDictSize(currentDictSize),w+w.charAt(0));
        w=entry;
        }

        }
        return result.toString().getBytes();

}
```

Comment: Guessing here: even the first `a` is encoded using 9 bits. Lower bits are in leftmost bytes, higher bits in the least significant bits of the byte to the right: the array reads 97,  129, 130, …

Comment: (The negative values are just due to foolishly printing Java's signed byte as decimal numbers. `have to convert the whole byte array to one binary string and read each value every 9 bits (codeword length)` You have bytes and need codes, so you need to convert. You don't need a `binary string` (so no need to care what *that* might be). It used to be common to use an *integer* with max value no smaller than (max code * max byte) as a conversion buffer.)

Comment: The encoding is `aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbA ccccccBB dddddCCC eeeeDDDD fffEEEEE ggFFFFFF hGGGGGGG HHHHHHHH` where each letter represents a single bit, and upper case letters are the most significant bits. Note that it takes 9 bytes to hold 8 codewords. So it may be useful to write a method that takes a 9 byte array as input, and returns an 8 codeword array as output.

Comment: Hmmm, i'm very confused now. The codeword size is given in bits, why are you talking about bytes then? I have another exercise where this is working fine:

The compressed text is here byte[] compressed = [68, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 32, 0, 105, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 32, 0, 101, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 32, 0, 107, 0, 117, 0, 114, 0, 122, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 32, 0, 84, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 116, 0] and a given codeword length of 16 bits.

The resulting string should be "Das ist ein kurzer Text". This works very well.

How can i apply this to the compressed byte array in the initial question? :)

Comment: I added some code to my initial question.

Comment: (`"Das ist ein kurzer Text". This works very well` note that it does not use a single code beyond the initial ones.)

Comment: Whats wrong with my code then? :)

Comment: (Dunno (yet - the target is moving))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code for reading *n-bit-codes LSB first*.
Beware dirty details like alignment on code size change.

```
/** An <code>NBitsInputStream</code> reads its <code>InputStream</code>
 *  as codes of n bits, least significant bits first.
 */// extend with set/increaseCodeLength() as needed
class NBitsInputStream extends java.io.FilterInputStream {
    int buffer, validBits;
    int codeLength, codeMask;
    protected NBitsInputStream(InputStream in, int n) {
        super(in);
        codeLength = n;
        codeMask = (1 << n) - 1;
    }
    /** Reads a code of n bits, least significant bits first.
     * @return  the code, or -1 if -1 is read. */
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        while (validBits < codeLength) {
            int high = super.read();
            if (high < 0)   // EOF
                return high;
            buffer |= high << validBits;
            validBits += 8;
        }
        int code = buffer & codeMask;
        validBits -= codeLength;
        buffer >>= codeLength;
        return code;
    }
}
```

(Tried

```
    for (int code ; 0 <= (code = codes.read()) ; ) {
        String entry = (String) dictionary.get(code);
        w += (null != entry ? entry : w).charAt(0);
        dictionary.put(++currentDictSize, w);
        result.append(w = entry);
    }
```

without unexpected observations.)

Note that your dictionary will contain not just the longest strings, but each of their prefixes, for up to about 2130641537 characters using 16 bit codes (in addition to a `result` of almost that length).

Comment: Sorry for my dumb questions, but i still dont understand how to use this. :)

Comment: Instead of `for (String k : binaryCompressedValues)`, you'd use `while (0 <= (code = codes.read()))` (and get an `int` - good for indexing, no advantage for `Map` access).

Comment: Can you give a more specific example. The above doesnt work. So i initialize first with NBitsInputStream codes = new NBitsInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedData), 16); and then..? :)

Comment: The construction is spot on. Using your second example value list, I get "the values without the `0`s". How does `[doesn't] work` show?